# \multicolumn in array not showing column separator

Tags: arrays, multicolumn

I'm trying to write three columns of equations separated by vertical lines in an array, but when I use the multicolumn command it doesn't show the column separator. I've tried using the multicols package but it messes up the formatting.

```
\[
\begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}r>{\displaystyle}l|>{\displaystyle}r>{\displaystyle}l|>{\displaystyle}r>{\displaystyle}l}
\frac{\delta^2\psi_L}{\delta x^2}& = -k^2Ce^{ikx}-k^2Re^{-ikx}&\frac{\delta^2\psi_C}{\delta x^2}& = A\kappa^2e^{\kappa x}+B\kappa^2e^{-\kappa x}&\frac{\delta^2\psi_R}{\delta x^2}& = -Tk^2e^{ikx}\\
&&&&&\\
&=-k^2\psi_L&&=\kappa^2\psi_C&&=-k^2\psi_R\\
&&&&&\\
&=-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}\psi_L&&=\frac{2m(V-E)}{\hbar^2}\psi_C&&=-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}\psi_R\\
&&&&&\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\mbox{Substitute into (1), }V=0}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\mbox{Substitute into (1)}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\mbox{Substitute into (1), }V=0}\\
&&&&&\\
E\psi_L&=E\psi_L&(E-V)\psi_C&=(E-V)\psi_C&E\psi_R&=\psi_R\\
\end{array}
\]
```

[image: Output:]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{\mbox{Substitute into (1), }V=0}
```

to give you a vertical rule at the end of your `multicolumn`. Here's a complete MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}r>{\displaystyle}l|>{\displaystyle}r>{\displaystyle}l|>{\displaystyle}r>{\displaystyle}l}
        \frac{\delta^2\psi_L}{\delta x^2} & = -k^2Ce^{ikx}-k^2Re^{-ikx} & \frac{\delta^2\psi_C}{\delta x^2} & = A\kappa^2e^{\kappa x}+B\kappa^2e^{-\kappa x} & \frac{\delta^2\psi_R}{\delta x^2} & = -Tk^2e^{ikx}              \\
                                          &                             &                                   &                                                &                                   &                             \\
                                          & =-k^2\psi_L                 &                                   & =\kappa^2\psi_C                                &                                   & =-k^2\psi_R                 \\
                                          &                             &                                   &                                                &                                   &                             \\
                                          & =-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}\psi_L &                                   & =\frac{2m(V-E)}{\hbar^2}\psi_C                 &                                   & =-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}\psi_R \\
                                          &                             &                                   &                                                &                                   &                             \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\mbox{Substitute into (1), }V=0}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\mbox{Substitute into (1)}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\mbox{Substitute into (1), }V=0}\\
                                          &                             &                                   &                                                &                                   &                             \\
        E\psi_L                           & =E\psi_L                    & (E-V)\psi_C                       & =(E-V)\psi_C                                   & E\psi_R                           & =\psi_R                     \\
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

As a note: it looks you are hard coding a reference using `(1)`; it's best to avoid this kind of thing, and use `\ref`, `\eqref` and friends.

You can get better spacing around your `=` symbols by using

```
    \begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}r@{}>{\displaystyle}l|>{\displaystyle}r@{}>{\displaystyle}l|>{\displaystyle}r@{}>{\displaystyle}l}
```

which removes the column separation; furthermore, you can use, for example

```
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
```

and remove the empty rows to set the row spacing.

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
    \begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}r@{}>{\displaystyle}l|>{\displaystyle}r@{}>{\displaystyle}l|>{\displaystyle}r@{}>{\displaystyle}l}
        \frac{\delta^2\psi_L}{\delta x^2} & {}= -k^2Ce^{ikx}-k^2Re^{-ikx} & \frac{\delta^2\psi_C}{\delta x^2} & {}= A\kappa^2e^{\kappa x}+B\kappa^2e^{-\kappa x} & \frac{\delta^2\psi_R}{\delta x^2} & {}= -Tk^2e^{ikx}              \\
                                          & {} =-k^2\psi_L                &                                   & {}=\kappa^2\psi_C                                &                                   & {} =-k^2\psi_R                \\
                                          & {}=-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}\psi_L &                                   & {} =\frac{2m(V-E)}{\hbar^2}\psi_C                &                                   & {}=-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}\psi_R \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\mbox{Substitute into (1), }V=0}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\mbox{Substitute into (1)}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\mbox{Substitute into (1), }V=0}\\
        E\psi_L                           & {} =E\psi_L                   & (E-V)\psi_C                       & {} =(E-V)\psi_C                                  & E\psi_R                           & {} =\psi_R                    \\
    \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Following `egreg's` suggestion, you can also use a new column type:

```
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\displaystyle}r@{}>{\displaystyle}l}
```

which allows you to write

```
\begin{array}{M|M|M}
```

You might also like to center the entries on the last row:

```
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{E\psi_L=E\psi_L}                   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{(E-V)\psi_C=(E-V)\psi_C}                                  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{E\psi_R=\psi_R}                    \\
```

Comment: Probably a factor 3 for `\arraystretch` is too much; the last row should be set with two `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{...}` and `\multicolumn{2}{c}`. If you define a new column type like `\newcolumntype{M}{>{\displaystyle}r@{}>{\displaystyle{}}l}}` you can avoid `{}` in front of `=` with a tabular preamble `M|M|M`.